# Why can't I move object?

Tags: transforms

I'm beginner and I don't know what I clicked to make it happens.
I can't neither move nor scale object, but the orange dot at the center of object.
Help please

[image: I see squares with each XYZ]
[image: I see redX greenY purpleZ at the end of lines]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uncheck *"origins"* (which is to move the object's origin only, the orange dot is the origin):

[image]

When objects have this colored X/Y/Z arrows that means this option is activated.

This options corresponds to the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>.</kbd> shorcut.

Comment: Thank you so much! Perhaps I used the short cut.